# Operating on a set of sequences - such as adding sequences and so on possible even when sequence is coded as number?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, set-theory

Suppose that there is a way to code some set of sequences into number. Then one is given one number. Suppose that we want to multiply all numbers in each sequence by that number and get the coded number of the resulting set of sequences. But we want to do this without decoding the number that uniquely represents soem set of sequences into sequences and operating on them.

Is there any way of coding that satisfies the above condition? All sequences are assumed to have same cardinality.

All sequences are of finite cardinality, all numbers are integers.

Additional question: And with all conditions above, would it be possible to append some number at the end of all sequences and get the coded number of the resulting set without decoding the sequences fully?

Edit: A set of sequences here is a set of $k$-tuples and $k$ can be set whatever one wishes to. But each set that is given as an input is assumed to have tuples that are of the same cardinality. And any number, whether it is a number that is to be multiplied, appended or is in a tuple, can be chosen from any number in integer range.

By "some set of sequences", I mean: {{elements of sequence 1}, {elements of sequence 2}, ..}. This set is of finite cardinality - that is, it contatins only finite sequences. And each sequence also contains finite elements. There are therefore countably infinite number of possible "some set of sequences".

The coding method is set to be uniform (that is, the coding works for all $k$) or the following: let's say that to some set of sequences, we want to add more sequences into the set. Then it must be possible that without decoding, two sets can be union-ed and converted into the coded number.

I do not know whether such coding exists, and that's why I asked this question.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are those real numbers? Integers? Are the sequences infinite?

Comment: All numbers are assumed to be integers. Sequences are finite.

Comment: That very much depends on the coding of the sequences. If you think of sequences of digits (decimal notation of the number, essentially) you can add a digit by multiplying by 10 and adding, no need to get the full sequence.

Comment: Do you mean you have a set of $k$-tuples of integers for some _fixed_ $k$? Can all integers be used in the sequences, or is it just integers from, say, $0, 1, 2, \ldots, m-1$?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I edited the question. And yes, all integers can be used in the sequences.

Comment: And I do not only consider multiplication by 10, but also by other integers.

Comment: Are you taking *all* the sequences, or just a set of sequences? When you say that the number uniquely represents our set, do we even know the encoding/decoding process? What is this encoding process? Is it uniform for all $k$, or do we have a different method for every $k$, and every set of $k$-tuples?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use a [Gödel numbering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering).
Let your set of sequences be
$$
\left\{ \{x_{11},x_{12},\ldots,x_{1N}\},\{x_{21},\ldots\,x_{2N}\},\ldots,\{x_{M1},\ldots,x_{MN}\} \right\}
$$

Then you can encode it as
$$
S = 2^M 3^N 5^{x_{11}} 7^{x_{21}} \cdots (p_{M+2})^{x_{M1}} (p_{M+3})^{x_{12}} \cdots (p_{MN+2})^{x_{MN}}
$$
or
$$
T = 2^M 3^N 5^{x_{11}} 7^{x_{12}} \cdots (p_{N+2})^{x_{1N}} (p_{N+3})^{x_{21}} \cdots (p_{MN+2})^{x_{MN}}
$$
where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime number.

Then if we want to multiply each $x_{ij}$ by $C$ the encoding is $$S^C 2^{(1-C)M} 3^{(1-C)N}$$

If encoded as $S$ then we can add an element to each set with the encoding
$$
3 S (p_{MN+3})^{x_{1,N+1}} \cdots (p_{M(N+1)+2})^{x_{M,N+1}}
$$

If encoded as T then we can add a new set with the encoding
$$
2 T (p_{MN+3})^{x_{M+1,1}} \cdots (p_{M(N+1)+2})^{x_{M+1,N}}
$$
Each of the above requires finding $M$ and $N$ but not the elements.

You can allow for both types of additions by iterating the numbering. Encode a sequence $X={x_1,\ldots,x_N}$ as
$$
K(X) = 2^N 3^{x_1}\cdots (p_N)^{x_N}
$$
then encode a sequence of sequences $X_1,\ldots,X_M$ as
$$
2^M 3^{K(X_1)} \cdots (p_M)^{K(X_M)}
$$
Now to add a new sequence we only need to find $M$; to multiply $X_i$ by $C$ we need to find $K(X_i)$; and to add an element to $X_i$ we need to find $K(X_i)$ and from that find $N$.